# A contents page displaying images

Tags: ms-word

I am creating a contents page in Word. For some reason, objects that I have pasted in from Visio are being shown in the page listing...

Why is this?

And more importantly, how can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

OK, easy as. Just had the images set as a heading.

Soz ppl.